# Save anonymous user data and map with the user after registeration or login in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Hello I have an app where user come he get list of items he select item as many he wish then he click on "add to cart " where he get redirect to page where he sees the item selected and total price , Now to proceed further i want user to login or register and after he login or register he gets map with the item and price he selected and data get save in database i have an app which works perfect for login user but i want it for anonymous user who first select items and then go for registeration/login.

```
models.py
class UserSelectTest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    testselected = models.TextField()

class UserTest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    number = models.IntegerField()
    location = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    time = models.IntegerField()
    totalprice = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True)
    test_submitted = models.BooleanField()
```

```
views.py 

def ResultTest(request):
    var = request.POST.get('selectedTests')
    abc = UserSelectTest()
    abc.user = request.user
    abc.testselected = request.POST['selectedTests']
    abc.save()


def PostTest(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test = UserTest()
        test.user = request.user
        test.name = request.POST['name']
        test.email = request.POST['email']
        test.number = request.POST['number']
        test.location = request.POST['location']
        test.time = request.POST['time']
        test.totalprice = request.POST['price']
        test.test_submitted = True
        test.save()
```

I views i have two function where "ResultTest" stores the item selected by the user and total price , and another view "PostTest" it stores the extra data. These is working perfectly for user who is already login.
Now I am trying for anonymous user with same work flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is store the session id of user into your cart model which I am assuming is `UserSelectTest`. You can add a field there

```
session_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True)
```

Further, you change your user field to allow null values for unregistered users.

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

In your veiws you can get any user's session id from `request.session.session_key`. You store the cart values for a non-registered user with that key. When a user registers, you simply update the `user` field for that user matching with his `session_id`, if any.

Comment: i want to store data in two model so i need to create session_id for both model ?if i create for both will id be same ? New to these so no idea

Comment: Yes add session_id fields in both models and make user field optional on both models.

Comment: Sorry if i am asking more can you just give me small example how to use session key in views as i tried and i am not  getting it

Comment: You do it the same way you are doing for other fields. `test.session_id = request.session.session_key`
And you also add it in your respective models like I have shown. Dont forget to migrate again after model change

Comment: okay got it ! and after user register how would mapping be done with id to user?

Comment: Search on how to update a model row. After user registeration you will update all model rows where session id is matching with current user's session. And furthermore for that user you will always store user data as well as session data.
Do upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you